# Select subset from dataframe, which contain elements in a given list

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe `df` and list members like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[20,21],[22,19],[30,27]], 'b':[22,13,7]})
members = [[20,21],[18,21],[15,18]]
```

I want to select the subset `df1` from `df` to let value of column 'a' in list members.

In the given case, I want to get the output like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[20,21]], 'b':[22]})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this carefully: [ask]. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Use `isin`

```
In [523]: df[df['a'].isin(members)]
Out[523]:
          a   b
0  [20, 21]  22
```

Or, `query`

```
In [530]: df.query('a in @members')
Out[530]:
          a   b
0  [20, 21]  22
```

Or, `apply` `in`

```
In [524]: df[df['a'].apply(lambda x: x in members)]
Out[524]:
          a   b
0  [20, 21]  22
```

Or, `list comprehension`

```
In [536]: df[[x in members for x in df['a']]]
Out[536]:
          a   b
0  [20, 21]  22
```

---

Details

```
In [525]: df
Out[525]:
          a   b
0  [20, 21]  22
1  [22, 19]  13
2  [30, 27]   7

In [526]: members
Out[526]: [[20, 21], [18, 21], [15, 18]]

In [527]: pd.__version__
Out[527]: '0.23.0.dev0+60.ge09189e'
```

Comment: hmmm, I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: what is your pandas, python version?

Comment: I use `pandas 0.22.0`

Comment: Ah, possible, might have been version addition then.

Comment: I think so too.

Comment: I think I should update my pandas since it does't work in my current version

Comment: @Zero The first two methods don't work. pandas version 0.22.0

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is convert values to tuples and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = df[df['a'].apply(tuple).isin([tuple(x) for x in members])]
print (df)
          a   b
0  [20, 21]  22
```

Comment: so list is not supported by isin

Comment: @JiaweiLu - exactly.

Comment: @JiaweiLu - For you working `df[df['a'].isin(members)]` ?

Comment: It doesn't work, indicating that Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2). pandas version 0.20.1